# Remap middle mouse button to key+mouse button

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, mouse, emulation

I've got a Bluetooth mouse that works, but the middle wheel button has stopped functioning reliably.

Frustratingly, due to other issues, I've had to disable all my USB ports (believe me, I had to) and now I can't use a CAD that relies on middle mouse dragging motions for changing views.

I originally encountered this issue in Blender, where I could simply enable `Emulate 3 button mouse`, where all middle-mouse gestures like dragging were activated when I held down the `alt` key and the left mouse button.

The software I'm using however has no mechanism for doing this, and all the scripts and programs I've found don't allow me to either combine keyboard and mouse, or only emulate the clicking action, rather than the moving one.

I really like Blender's method as the `alt` key is easy to get to and it works reliably. I'm wondering if there is a solution to this, either through script or an external application.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to get a new mouse?

Comment: It has crossed my mind, but it was a gift, and i'm a bit sentimental about that kind of thing 

Comment: Nothing lasts forever, unfortunately.

Comment: that's very true. I guess I'm going mouse shopping...